# Update database using code first without using PM Console Command

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity, entity-framework-5

I got this problem that make me mad many days. I write a console application, using code first to create a new database, and using migration to update it. It work very good. But, when I write a wcf service to do the same thing like the console application, it doesn't work as I want. The problem is i can't update the database using code but the command (Update-Database -Verbose) on PM console can do it. Can you give me some suggestion?
Here is my code:
Configuration.cs

```
public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(DatabaseInitialization.DatabaseModel context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
        //
        //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
        //      p => p.FullName,
        //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
        //    );
        //
    }
```

Migration file:

```
public partial class InitialCreate : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

Main file:

```
public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {  

        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DatabaseModel, DatabaseInitialization.Migrations.Configuration>());
        InitializeDatabase();

        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
        config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
    }

    public static void InitializeDatabase()
    {
        var context = new DatabaseModel();           
        context.Database.Initialize(true);
    }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Angry as a cut snake with EF. :-)

Try

```
Context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
```

or use the Initializer

```
Database.SetInitializer(new  CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<TContext>
```

Seems that migrations work nicely once you have a DB.
Create if not exist is step one.

Comment: Hi soadyp, I definitely created a db, and i want to migrate changes to it. I declared Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseModel>(null) in the construction but no luck.